# Problem plotting geometries in Choropleth map using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot census level data and geometries to plotly mapbox. While I am able to plot the base map, the colored polygons used to represent spatial data is missing.

```
import pandas as pd 
import geopandas as gpd
import mapbox
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import *

df_geo = gpd.read_file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uscensusgeo.geojson')


import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=df_geo['geometry'].to_json(), 
                                    locations=df_geo['TRACTCE'], 
                                    z=df_geo['ALAND'],
                                    colorscale="Viridis", 
                                    zmin=df_geo['ALAND'].min(), 
                                    zmax=df_geo['ALAND'].max(), 
                                    marker_line_width=0))

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="light", 
                  mapbox_accesstoken=token,
                  mapbox_zoom=3, 
                  mapbox_center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                  margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

fig.update_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]

The colored polygons are missing from the map above.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected error while fetching from {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "0", "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-81.375782, 28.411135], [-81.372696, 28.421524], [-81.368127, 28.43621], [-81.366996, 28.440684], [-81.366866, 28.445807], [-81.364976, 28.4458], [-81.361445, 28.445845], [-81.358309, 28.446668], [-81.350651, 28.450405], [-81.351092, 28.449687], [-81.349923, 28.449939],
```

Comment: @RobRaymond figured you might have some thoughts on this.

Comment: Wasn't this question already resolved by my answer? Is it a different question?